# C++ How to distinguish Multimap with duplicate keys with value and and Unique keys with values in different map containers with O(n) traversal

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, stl

Hi I would like to seperate multimap  with two seperate Map containers

`multimap<string,string> MulMap // Multimap Container`
`map <string,string> DuplicateKeyValueMap`
`map <string,string> UniqueKeyValueMap`

Upon MulMap Iteration I am able to separate duplicate keys and unique keys using `count` and `equal_range`
I googled and got info that this approach takes O(n log n) complexity.

Is there a better way than this to code to achieve O(n) complexity?

Comment: What has this to do with Windows?!

Comment: Sorry I have removed it .

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to tell whether two maps contains the same elements, the straight-forward algorithm (which is O(n)) works:

```
return m1.size() == m2.size() &&
       std::equal(m1.begin(), m1.end(), m2.begin());
```

You have to look at every unique map element at least once, and doing that is also sufficient. Since both maps are ordered, you can stop as soon as you find a mismatch.

In C++14 you can use the simpler four-iterator form:

```
return std::equal(m1.begin(), m1.end(), m2.begin(), m2.end());
```